# Is my sentence correct ? (using "for" or "of a")

Tags: prepositions, sentence-construction

I'm currently correcting some writing of mine. I have a question about this line in particular :

> To you I'm just a statistic, or a top tier choice for a stick

Is "for" adequate ? Or should I write "of a stick" ? Maybe even something else ?
The meaning of this is sex-related. "Statistic" meaning something like "just one more guy on your palmares". "Stick", meaning males' attribute

Comment: Could you add some context so we can make sense of the words you're asking about?

Comment: Sure, the meaning of this is sex-related. "Statistic" meaning something like "just one more guy on your palmares". 
"Stick", meaning males' attribute.

Comment: Most English speakers would not use "stick" in this way; it doesn't convey the meaning you intend.   (If you intended a rhyme, I'm not quite sure why but those words also don't rhyme as well as they appear to.)  Also "just a statistic" can idiomatically imply the subject has died.

(cmp. "just a line on a graph / a superior shaft"?)

Comment: palmarès  is French, not English.

Answer (score 0):

*I'm ... a ... choice for a(n) X*  implies slightly that you have to go through me to get X, and I'm a gateway to X.

*I'm ... a ... choice of a(n) X* means implies that I am not part of you acquiring X and you are not even worried about what I could do to stop you.  It's a bit more dehumanizing.

Note that:

- Saying "I'm just a statistic" is derogatory and dehumanizing, but this conflicts with *top tier* which is something anyone would like to be.  Not sure if you mean this or not.
- *Stick* sounds silly as a euphemism for male genitals, unless you are being artistic/poetic/lyrical with language (it does go with the sound of *statistic*).
- @BadZen is right about the implication of death, or crime.